# Parts of https://jenkins.io is down. How do I report it?

Tags: jenkins, issue-tracking, http-status-code-503, downtime, http-status-code-502

So https://www.jenkins.io/ has been down for at least most of the afternoon. The main page is accessible, but blog posts and plugins etc. aren't available. I get a 503 that looks like this:

[image: 503 from https://www.jenkins.io/]

I figured I'd try again later, but since it was still down I thought I'd better report it. So I went to their JIRA to report the issue at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/, which seems to be up, but when trying to log in I get a 502 response, with the following error message:

[image]

I went to their [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins), but they have issues disabled there. I'm running out of options, so I figured I'd ask here to see if there is someone that knows how to get in touch with someone that knows how to fix it. I found a few tweets about it, but no responses from anyone that seems to be able to do anything about it.

Comment: Thankfully it seems to be fixed now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the issue was resolved and I was able to log in to JIRA, I found a way to report the issue and apparently a few people already did. If this happens again, you can go to https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/issues/ and report the issue there.

Another place to check is the `jenkins-infra` channel on `freenode`, as that's where they are discussing the issue during investigation.

In case you were curious, it seems like this outage was due to a problem with the Kubernetes cluster where it was hosted. I don't know any more details than that.

I hope this might help someone in the future.

Comment: Great references, I was experiencing an issue with Jenkins infra today and followed your reference to join #jenkins-infra, where I found this helpful status page showing the outage issues in /topic: https://p.datadoghq.com/sb/0Igb9a-a5ff8c4199

Comment: is there any mirrors of get.jenkins.io/plugins?

Comment: Thanks @Kingdon, that looks very useful. :)